# How does OpenCV function Grab work in Windows?

Tags: windows, opencv

I am trying to understand the low-level functionality of the OpenCV function grab, in particular I want to understand what OS functions it calls in windows.

I am having a hard time tracking down what actually happens in the source code, I went to the videoio source code but it doesn't have any windows specific calls in it.

Can someone explain or link me to the functions OpenCV actually calls when interacting with USB cameras on USB machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just look at those files,

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_winrt

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_winrt_capture.cpp

opencv uses Windows MediaCapture Class

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture?view=winrt-19041

Comment: I looked a little more and ther is some backend sending a letting you also use directsshow. I'm interested in low level camera control and trying to pull images at deterministic times. Not sure if it's possible.

Comment: you may want to follow WIA (Windows Image Acquisition) tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/windows/win32/wia/-wia-wia-tutorial?redirectedfrom=MSDN